# Android App doesn't get back after logging

Tags: xamarin, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, xamarin.auth

I'm trying to implement OAuth through google in my xamarin app. My code looks like :

```
var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator
(
    clientId: clientId,
    scope: scope,
    authorizeUrl: new Uri(oauthUrl),
    redirectUrl: new Uri(redirectUrl),
    clientSecret: clientSecret,
    accessTokenUrl: new Uri(accessTokenUrl), 
    getUsernameAsync: null, 
    isUsingNativeUI:true
);

auth.Completed += AuthOnCompleted;
auth.Error += AuthOnError;

var presenter = new Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.OAuthLoginPresenter();
presenter.Login(auth);


private async void AuthOnCompleted(object sender, AuthenticatorCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    //breakpoint, which never reach
}

private async void AuthOnError(object sender, AuthenticatorErrorEventArgs e) 
{
    //breakpoint, which never reach
}
```

The flow goes correct until redirection.

> redirectUrl = https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

After successfully logging I got to url kind of this :

> https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?state=ojgjqhcgyidimcec&code=4/0AX4XfwjvhStjH5RAAzLyXCu_dTPvPyZ_eee-gHqKZoglVJ-7PCR6HDkPAo9mfEMYnWdjyA&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly

It's clear that we have got user token, but app doesn't go next step, to `AuthOnCompleted` method. App just staying on redirect URL. How to close browser and get back to app into `AuthOnCompleted`?

**UPD**

**MainActivity.cs:**

```
[Activity(Label = "MyApp", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true,
        ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation |
        ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize)]
[IntentFilter(
    actions: new[] { Intent.ActionView }, 
    Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryDefault, Intent.CategoryBrowsable },
    DataSchemes = new[]
    {
        "com.googleusercontent.apps.Project ID from https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=my_proj",
    },
    DataPaths = new[]
    {
        "/oauth2redirect",
    })]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        global::Xamarin.Auth.Presenters.XamarinAndroid.AuthenticationConfiguration.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
{
    Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
}
```

Comment: can you put the code of  log instead of image?

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT what do you mean?

Comment: I mean in text not screenshots

Comment: try add following code in the end of  your OnCreate method "new Task(() =>{
         StartActivity(new Intent(Application.Context,typeof(MainActivity)));
     }).Start();"

Comment: according to this https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Auth/blob/master/docs/details/issues/open/native-ui-android-customtabs-close.md

Comment: @AdrainZhu-MSFT I added this code after `LoadApplication(new App());`  in `MainActivity` class.  unfortunately it broke my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found a working solution here
https://github.com/TimLariviere/Sample-XamarinAuth-Google

My mistake was I wrote `DataSchemes` as `com.googleusercontent.apps.Project ID` but correct is `com.companyname.testapp` package name